# Getting the Gaussian model weight

Tags: c++, opencv, model, gaussian

I am wondering how to get single model weight from several Gaussian mixture models in OpenCV. For 
For instance, if the number of models is five for GMM I want to get the weight of the second or third model.

Could someone help me on this? Another saying, I want to know which model is the mostly used one among these five?